# My sound isn't working

Tags: drivers, sound

I was watching YouTube and the sound went out. My sound is not on mute.

Comment: Does sound play as root user?

Comment: Also what is the output of sudo aplay -l

Comment: Is the correct output device selected in Sound Settings?